# How to prove $\mathcal O_X(m)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_X(n)= \mathcal O_X(m+n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $B$ be a graded ring and $X=\mathrm {Proj}\: B$. Let $B(m)$ denote the twist of $B$ (i.e. a graded $B$-module such that $B(m)_d=B_{m+d}$,) $\mathcal O_X(m)$ denote the quasi-coherent sheaf $\tilde{B(m)}$. Then how to prove the statement 
$\mathcal O_X(m)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_X(n)= \mathcal O_X(m+n)$? (The statement is from Liu’s book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.)

Let $B(m)_{(g)}$ denote the set of elements of degree 0 in the localized ring $B(m)_{g} $ for any homogeneous $g$ with a positive degree. Then it is equivalent to
$$B(m)_{(g)}\otimes_{B_{(g)}} B(n)_{(g)}\simeq B(m+n)_{(g)} $$
for any homogeneous $g$ with a positive degree. The isomorphism is obvious if $\mathrm D_+(g)\subseteq \mathrm D_+(f)$ for some $f$ of degree 1, but such an $f$ may not exist.

Set $m=n=1$ and $\mathrm{deg}\: g =2$, what is the isomorphism above exactly? I can not find it.

[image: Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves]

Comment: @reuns OK, I defined them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason for this map to be an isomorphism in general - in fact, it's not even true that $\mathcal{O}_X(n)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(m) = \mathcal{O}_X(n+m)$ in general! See [Stacks 01MJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MJ) for counterexamples, and [Stacks 01MM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MM), specifically [01MT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MT) for more details about when this is true - it's true for instance if $B$ is generated by $B_1$ as a $B_0$ algebra.

Comment: I get this statement from Liu’s book. So he is wrong about this.

Comment: @user150248 I doubt Liu is wrong. Most people work in the setting where $B$ is indeed generated in degree $1$, so he probably assumes this somewhere earlier.

Comment: @TabesBridges I did not find that.